# Get URL parameter passed to google form via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I`m trying to get URL parameter passed to google form via apps script, but don't know exactly how does it does. Case:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXX/viewform?a=12
(Passed XXXX, cause this form is for clients use)
and I need to get answers and this parameter after submit.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    var POST_UR​L = "www.myserver.com?id=a";//this parametr
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    var payload = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        payload[question] = answer;
    }
  
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
};
```

​​
This code made for sending POST request with answers of form to my server and how can I pass the ​a=12 or only 12 to this request?

Comment: How is the url `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXX/viewform?a=12` relevant in your code? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the values to `POST_URL` instead of passing via payload. There's a nice bit of code provided by Google in their [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/48d04cae685f11951859c37494a1e469d1e1dc0b/src/Utilities.js#L20) that will do this for you:

```
/**
 * Builds a complete URL from a base URL and a map of URL parameters.
 * @param {string} url The base URL.
 * @param {Object.<string, string>} params The URL parameters and values.
 * @return {string} The complete URL.
 * @private
 */
function buildUrl_(url, params) {
  var paramString = Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
  }).join('&');
  return url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + paramString;
}
```

Which means you can do something like:

```js
var POST_URL = "www.myserver.com?id=a";
var payload = {a: 12};
console.log(buildUrl_(POST_URL, payload)); // www.myserver.com?id=a&a=12

function buildUrl_(url, params) {
  var paramString = Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
  }).join('&');
  return url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + paramString;
}
```

Ultimately, the final line in your code would be:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(buildUrl_(POST_URL, payload), options);
```

Comment: And which way can I get "a" parameter? if It is dynamical

Comment: `payload.a` ...? Sorry @user14061595 but I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: It means that user goes to https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXX/viewform?a=12 and I need to get a parameter, but it can be any digit.

Comment: And with google script send to server answers and query parameter